# getElementById(e.target.value) equivalent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function works as intended but I would like to stick with jQuery. I am not sure what the equivalent in jQuery is for getElementById when that id is dependent on an event.

Code

```
$("#language").change(function(e){
     $('[name="filler_char_types"]').css('display', 'none').prop('disabled', false);
     document.getElementById(e.target.value).style.display = "block"; 
});
```

Comment: Just do `$('#' + e.target.value).show()`.

Comment: Yes  " $('#' + e.target.value).show() " this is short and easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$()`like below:

```
$("#language").change(function(e){
  $('[name="filler_char_types"]').css('display', 'none').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#'+ e.target.value).css('display','block'); // or use $('#'+ e.target.value).show() 
});
```